# Is romantic love permissible before marriage?

Tags: nikah, relationships

Love is an uncontrollable feeling.* It may happen blindly. My questions are:

1. Is it allowed in Islam?
2. Can a guy and girl fall in love with one another before marriage?
3. What if you love someone with the intention to get married later on?

What does Shari'ah say to these questions?

<sub>*I'm not talking about making love (sexual relationship), of course that's a sin.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

> If a man feels some attraction towards a woman whom it is permissible
>   for him to marry her, and vice versa, there is no answer to the
>   problem except marriage. The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be
>   upon him) said: “We do not think that there is anything better for
>   those who love one another than marriage.” (Narrated by Ibn Maajah,
>   1847; classed as saheeh by al-Busayri and by Shaykh al-Albaani in
>   al-Silsilah al-Saheehah, 624)

However!

> But if that marriage comes about as a result of an illicit love
>   relationship, such as when they meet and are alone together and kiss
>   one another, and other haraam actions, then it will never be stable,
>   because they committed actions that go against sharee’ah and because
>   they have built their lives on things that will have the effect of
>   reducing blessings and support from Allaah, for sin is a major factor
>   in reducing blessings, even though some people think, because of the
>   Shaytaan’s whispers, that falling in love and doing haraam deeds makes
>   marriage stronger.

You can read the full fatwa here:
http://islamqa.info/en/ref/23420

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is allowed, and the best things for those who love/like each other is marriage.  This is clear in the Narration from the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him):

> لَمْ نَرَ لِلْمُتَحَابَّيْنِ مِثْلَ النِّكَاحِ
>
> For those who like each other, nothing has been proven as good as marriage (Translation from Islamic Online university Notes)

[Sunan Ibn Majah](http://sunnah.com/urn/1319210)

So if a man and a women like each other, then the best thing is to get married, and not go to sin.  I ask Allah for forgiveness of all my shortcomings, and I ask Him to guide us all.

Comment: It was narrated from Aishah that :
the Messenger of Allah said: “Any woman whose marriage is not arranged by her guardian, her marriage is invalid, her marriage is invalid, her marriage is invalid. If (the man) has had intercourse with her, then the Mahr belongs to her in return for his intimacy with her. And if there is any dispute then the ruler is the guardian of the one who does not have a guardian.”

 Sunan Ibn Majah » The Chapters on Marriage
https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:1879

Comment: _So if a man and a women like each other,..._ How can the man and woman know whether or not they like each other without first spending an adequate amount of time together? As the OP said, love is an uncontrollable feeling. Many times, you fall in love with someone without planning for it. How can someone "fall in love" if they don't even talk comfortably with one another? It does not seem to me that there is room for love marriages in our Deen.